# Escapar ' o " adentro de la string que reemplaza - sed

Tags: sed

se que se puede escapar `/` haciendo `\/` pero cuando intento lo mismo con ' o " no funciona. ej:

esto funciona

```
sed 's/=/="><something>/g' in.txt > out.txt
```

pero si intento agregar ' adentro del string que reemplaza, no funciona

```
sed 's/=/='"><something>/g' in.txt > out.txt
```

or

```
sed 's/=/=\'"><something>/g' in.txt > out.txt
```

entonces como escapo ' adentro de la string que reemplza?

Comment: Uh perdon, le re pifie.

Comment: Listo! ya esta traducido

Answer (score 1):

Ok despues de una busqueda rapida encontre que se puede hacer usando url encodings, entonces:

```
sed 's/aa/bb\x27"><aaa>/g' in.txt > out.txt
```

resulta:

```
bb'"><aaa>
```

No sabia que se podian usar url encodings para escapar caracteres pero es una buena solucion.